# Makefile file matching sources from different subfolders into single build folder

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, avr-gcc

I want to create a make file that takes all files in several src subdirectories and compiles them each directly into one single build directory.

I.e. i have e.g.

- src/main.c
- src/i2c/i2c.c
- src/i2c/i2c.h

and as output i want the object files as well as the final binary
 - build/main.o
 - build/i2c.o
 - build/release.elf

I manage to get all source files as a list with their respective subdirectory paths into a variable and I also manage to get a list of all output files but when i try to create a target to build all .o files in that build directory it does not match the corresponding .c files with the .o files. Here i am just not sure how to link these two.

It fails while trying to match main.o with i2c.c.

Here is "relevant" part of the Makefile:

```
TARGET = $(lastword $(subst /, ,$(CURDIR)))

BUILD_DIR  := buildDir

SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c src/*/*.c)
BROKENOBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
LESSBROKEN = $(notdir $(BROKENOBJECTS))
OBJECT_FILES = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(LESSBROKEN))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCES) $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR) :
    mkdir -p $@

compile : $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf
```

How would I go about this, running the recipe for each .c file from $(SOURCES) and just create the corresponding .o file in buildDir/ ?

Comment: Do all of your `*.c` files have unique names?  i.e. if there is a file `i2c.c` in the directory `src/i2c` then no other source directory will have a file named `i2c.c`.

Comment: For now it won't. I might have a case in the distant future where i want to link a different implementation to that, but in that case i think i would "just" include a different source folder with that specific implementation into it. Or add that source file specifically. For now everything existing should be included.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `make`'s [`vpath` mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search).  So, rather than specifying possible source paths using...

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c src/*/*.c)
```

you would have...

```
# Build a list of directories under src
#
SOURCE_DIRS := $(shell find src -type d)

# Use the list in $(SOURCE_DIRS) as a search path for .c files.
#
vpath %.c $(SOURCE_DIRS)
```

Now, when attempting to update `i2c.o` (for example), the rule...

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<
```

will cause `make` to automatically search through the list of source directories for the dependency `i2c.c`.

---

**Note:** For obvious reasons multiple files with the same name under different source directories will cause problems here.  Hence my original question (in the comments) regarding the *uniqueness* of source file names under different directories.

Comment: So far this seems to solve my problem exactly as i expected. Quite the clever thing. I would like to upvote this, but don't have yet enough reputation to do so... Thank you anyway for your answer!

Comment: Not quite.  The `vpath` directive tells `make` to search for any name matching the `%.c` pattern under the list of directories specified by `$(SOURCE_DIRS)`.

Comment: Sure, but where would the problem lie in that then? I might be missing something

Comment: So let's say you have two files `src/a/i2c.c` and `src/b/i2c.c`.  Which one should be used to build `$(BUILD_DIR)/i2c.o`?

Comment: i think for special cases where i have e.g. platform dependent code as in that example, I would put those into a separate src folder on the same level as and add a separate concrete rule for compiling those and linking them separately, depending on the target platform I want to compile. That will most likely require some extra amount of tweaking, I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use GNU make and your C source files are all `*.c` that can be found in the current directory and all its subdirectories (up to any depth), this should be close to what you want:

```
BUILDDIR := build
SRC      := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.c')

# Convert C source file name(s) to object file name(s)
# $(1): C source file name(s)
define c2o
$(patsubst %.c,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(1)))
endef

OBJ := $(call c2o,$(SRC))

.PHONY: all

all: $(OBJ)

# Compilation rule for a C source file (use echo for testing)
# $(1): C source file name
define MY_rule
$$(call c2o,$(1)): $(1)
    @echo $$(CC) $$(CFLAGS) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $$@ $$<
endef

# Instantiate compilation rules for all C source files
$(foreach s,$(SRC),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(s))))
```

Demo:

```
host> tree .
.
├── Makefile
├── a.c
├── b
│   └── b.c
└── c
    └── c
        └── c.c

host> make
cc -c -o build/a.o a.c
cc -c -o build/c.o c/c/c.c
cc -c -o build/b.o b/b.c
```

Note the use of `$$` in the definition of `MY_rule`. It is needed because it gets expanded twice: one time when expanding the parameters of the `eval` function and a second time when make parses the result as regular make syntax.

As explained in other comments and answers this works only if you don't have several C source files with the same base name. There is a way to detect this situation and issue an error if it is encountered. The make `sort` function sorts its word list parameter but it also removes duplicates. So, if the word count before and after sorting differ, you have duplicates. Add the following just after the definition of `OBJ`:

```
SOBJ     := $(sort $(OBJ))

ifneq ($(words $(OBJ)),$(words $(SOBJ)))
$(error Found multiple C source files with same base name)
endif
```

Demo:

```
host> touch c/c/a.c
host> make
Makefile:13: *** Found multiple C source files with same base name.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified snippet that should do what you want, though I didn't find a solution without specifying each subdirectory in `src/` manually.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard src/*.c)
SUBSOURCES = $(wildcard src/*/*.c)

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.c=.o)))
SUBOBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(notdir $(SUBSOURCES:.c=.o)))

compile : $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) $(SUBOBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# save some typing for the rules below
COMPILE = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(COMPILE)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/i2c/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(COMPILE)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/someOtherSubdir/%.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(COMPILE)
```

As @G.M. suggested in the comments, you must make sure that source file names are unique across subdirectories. Note also that I turned `$(BUILD_DIR)` into an [order only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types), which should reflect your intention more precisely.

Comment: I feared that this is for now the case. I was specifically trying to avoid having to add each new subfolder when extending my program. Feels a bit...inconvenient.

Comment: Maybe someone else might come up with a solution?! Though you could also take the inconvenience as a hint that a different approach might be better? :) There is nothing wrong e.g. with subfolders in your `$(BUILD_DIR)` identical to those in `src/`.

Comment: I actually saw that, but the examples it seemed shockingly more complicated that I though it is not worth it. How would that actually look alternatively, if the same folder structure is created in the build folder? I struggled with creating the subdirectories accordingly.

Comment: Can't tell you now off the top of my head. And could be that it increases the complexity of the makefile. Do you have so many subdirectories that listing them like in the snippet above is such a pain?